# How to add additional file fields to ruby on rails project?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Yesterday I have made paperclip multiple upload gallery. Today I want to customize this all and I need to make a button with on click add one more file upload field. Example you can see in this video: http://www.emersonlackey.com/article/rails-paperclip-multiple-file-uploads 28:27.

I have searched in google, but couldn't find anything.

@post form:

```
   <% form_for @post, :html => {:multipart => true}  do |t| %>
            <p>
                <%= t.label :title, 'Virsraksts:' %></br>
                <%= t.text_field :title %></br>
            </p>
            <p>
                <%= t.label :content, 'Teksts:' %>
                <%= t.text_area :content, :class => "mceEditor"%>
            </p>

            <p>Pievienot jaunas bildes:</p>
            <%= f.link_to_add "Add a task", :assets %>
            <%= f.fields_for :assets do |asset_fields| %>           
                <% if asset_fields.object.new_record? %>
                    <%= asset_fields.file_field :asset %>
                    <%= asset_fields.link_to_remove "Noņemt" %>
                <% end %>
            <% end %>

            <p>
                <%= f.fields_for :assets do |asset_fields| %>
                    <% unless asset_fields.object.new_record? %>
                    <p>
                        <%= link_to image_tag(asset_fields.object.asset.url(:thumb)), asset_fields.object.asset.url(:original) %>
                        <%= asset_fields.check_box :_destroy %>
                    </p>
                    <% end %>
                <% end %>
            </p>    
        <%= t.submit %>
```

@post model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :content, :assets_attributes
    has_many :assets
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets, :allow_destroy => true 
end
```

@asset model:

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  has_attached_file :asset, :styles => { :large => "640x480", :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" },
                        :url => "/assets/albums/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                        :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/albums/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :post, :allow_destroy => true 
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need the javascript to make the functions to work.

If you are a railscasts premium user you can access the link above, as Said recommended, but if you not, you should take a look at [this link](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2).

Comment: I have added .js files to my app.

Comment: Remove link is working fine, but add link does this error: undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @RydelHouse I can't find the code relative to the `add_link` in your post above.

Comment: Sorry, it's because I am testing it and trying to add in right place. I have updated again 1st post, but now I have another problem - my add file field link do nothing. :(

Comment: It doesn't make sense you have 2 `fields_for` in your `form`. 

Please consider take a look at [this code](https://github.com/klebershimabuku/classified/blob/master/app/views/posts/_form.html.erb) that I have implemented and it's working fine.

Answer (score 2):

There's a great cast from R.Bates about nested form [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised). i've modified it so that it's now possible to add, remove photos, works with paperclip, Feel free to clone this rails3.2 app https://github.com/Saidbek/multiple-image-uploader

Comment: Ok, now I have made link which removes my file fields, but I can't to add link which makes new one. In my first post I have updated all codes.